# Formatting ruby hash strings for console logs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a Rails app, and I have some variables I'm printing to my browser console through my view file.  In particular, I've created a ruby hash that has the following format:

```
{string: [array], string: [array]}
```

So, for example, one possible array I might have is

```
{'nil': [1,2, 3], "124": [4,5], "124/125": [6]}
```

When it gets printed to the browser console, the formatting is off.  For example, right now I have:

```
{nil=&gt;[1, 2, 3], &quot;124&quot;=&gt;[4, 5], &quot;124/217&quot;=&gt;[6]}
```

How can I get rid of the extra characters added in?

Here's my actual code:

```
<% allBranches = Hash.new %>
<% currentBranch = Array.new %>

<% (1..@ancestry.length-1).each do |index| %>
    <% if @ancestry[index] == @ancestry[index-1] %>
        <% currentBranch.push(index) %>
    <% else %>
        <% allBranches[@ancestry[index-1]]=currentBranch %>
        <% currentBranch = Array.new %>
        <% currentBranch.push(index) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("allBranches: <%=allBranches%>");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `html_safe`.

`console.log("allBranches: <%=allBranches.to_s.html_safe%>");`

If `allBranches` is already a string, the `to_s` part is unnecessary and redundant.

Comment: thanks for your help!  I'm getting the error "undefined method html_safe" for the hash.

Comment: Oh, right, allBranches is not a string.  I just edited the answer to add `to_s`.